# ASHX seems run more than one time

Tags: asp.net, .net, ashx

I have an ashx to do some sync work; it usually takes about 8 minutes. When the sync finishes, an email will be sent to admin. But when I run that ashx in browser, it keeps on loading forever after it finishes, so that admin gets more than one email.

Can anyone give me some information about why this happens?

Comment: What is the caller of this handler (client-side or server-side)?

Comment: Just input this ashx file url into browser to test.

Comment: Is it returning data in response? And what is the response type?

Comment: Well you could log the request and check if it is being called more than once.

Answer (score 0):

If the handler is not returning data to the response, maybe the browser is trying to request again until get a successful status. In this case, you may try to response any text just for retrieve success:

```
context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
context.Response.Write(string.Empty);
```

But, if the handler is returning data to the response and the response status code is successful, you may try to stop the response just after send the e-mail:

```
context.Response.End();
return;
```

And, just for check, verify if you are iterating over a loop that calls the mail sending more than one time.